# Reseting branch for GitHub pull request

Tags: github, pull-request

For one open source project, I opened pull request with commits in my branch. This PR stayed untouched for a few months.

Then, I did rebasing in that branch (because in the meantime it got conflict with master) and I messed something up so pull request got hundreds of commits from tens of contributors, and they are all added as "participants" to PR by GitHub. (I am not sure why GitHub is showing changes when those commits are from master, already merged)

I reverted rebasing in my local branch with `git reset` and it looks good, but I am wondering can I safely push that branch to origin? Will `git push --force` do the trick? If I do it, will those other commits be unaffected? What about participants to PR?

Note that this open source project is not mine, and that nobody else worked on my branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will git push --force do the trick?

Yes, it will update/replace the PR commit history by your local one, and update the participants.

If you want to test it, you can push it to a new branch and create a PR from that new branch to see if the end-result PR looks OK.
And then delete that new PR, and force push to your original branch.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. I did `git push --force` and it cleaned pull request. Also, I will make new branch and then try to create PR when I finish rebasing to confirm that everything is correct. Thanks for the tip!